# Django: SELECT ... FROM ONLY table

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Can Django do `SELECT ... FROM ONLY ...` queries without using `.raw()`?

I need it to omit archived tables in my queries to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a hg grep on 'ONLY' in django/db of the development version.
No hits, so no.

What's the bigger picture? Why not use .raw()?