# Django with postgresql db, query with ONLY keyword to look only parent table?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, inheritance

I have a table my django model is pointing to, db side i set a series of triggers to route information in child tables (by table inheritance) for a rotation system. Querying the parent table i can still have my full set of information even if dislocated in many tables,but to improve my performance i want to search only in parent table, corresponding with a query where i specify "ONLY" to make db not search in child tables. Is there a way to do it with django models?

Comment: Why are you looking to improve performance?  This is often a trap that programmers get into.  You shouldn't look to improve performance, unless there is a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posible duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733437/django-select-from-only-table)

You can create a view in postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT * FROM ONLY MY_TABLE;
```

Create a model in django pointing to that view:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_view'
```

Then query that model.
Or you can use directly [.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries)